# How to assign a structure with a uin8_t array?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a compilation error when i attempt to compile the following simple code:

```
uint8_t latestMessageID[4];

struct Notification {
    uint8_t uuid[4];
    ...
};

Notification notificationList[NOTIFICATION_LIST_SIZE];

void setup()
{
    Notification notificationList[NOTIFICATION_LIST_SIZE];
    notificationList[0].uuid = latestMessageID; // Compilation error here
    ...
}
```

Error:

> expression must be a modifiable lvalue

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/u9BT5q)

**What is the cause of this error and how can i approach a solution?**

Comment: Choose a language. C and C++ may have different answers. For example, in c++ we would say use a `std::array` which has a copy assignment operator.

Comment: A UUID is 128-bit (16 byte) so this name is misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign an array like this. If you are actually using `c++` (and 11) you can utilize something like `std::array`:

```
using uuid_t = std::array<uint8_t, 16>;

struct Notification {
    uuid_t uuid;
    ...
```

Which acts exactly the same, occupies the same space, but provides an `operator=`. So this would be possible:

```
notificationList[0].uuid = latestMessageID;
```

*Assuming `latestMessageID` is also a `std::array`*

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/pFqJ1Z)

Other options for pre-c++11 include `boost::array` and if you are ok with memory allocation (or even if not and can provide a custom allocator) you could use `std::vector`.

As a further note, be aware that the `notificationList` is declared twice, globally and in the function `setup`. These are not the same object, and the one that you are assigning to in `setup` will go out of scope at the end of that function and the changes you made will be lost.

Comment: May i add that you can also name it with a pretty name like `using uuid_t = std::array<uint8_t, 4>; uuid_t uuid;`

Comment: In additions, how about make `uuid` more [*"pentium 4"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)  friendly by align its parent :`struct alignas(16) Notification {`.

Comment: @sandthorn I think that is outside the scope of the question. It is a good suggestion, but maybe will add fluff that draws away from the point of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `uuid` is an array type, you cannot assign *to* an array type.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy an array this way:

```
notificationList[0].uuid = latestMessageID;
```

You must copy each element of the array. You can use [`memcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) for that:

```
memcpy(notificationList[0].uuid, latestMessageID, sizeof latestMessageID);
```

Comment: For POD types, `memcpy()` is OK. But that is the C way to copy data. In C++, you should prefer `std::copy()` instead. It is optimized for POD arrays, but also works for non-POD arrays too.

Answer (score 0):

You had to copy element by element:

```
notificationList[0].uuid[0] = latestMessageID[0];
notificationList[0].uuid[1] = latestMessageID[1];
notificationList[0].uuid[2] = latestMessageID[2];
notificationList[0].uuid[3] = latestMessageID[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't assign to arrays -- they're not modifiable l-values

```
Notification notificationList[NOTIFICATION_LIST_SIZE];
memcpy(notificationList[0].uuid, latestMessageID, 4);
```